# Change a variable from a function

Tags: python-3.x

I need to change a variable from inside a function, with the variable being an argument.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
bar = False

def someFunction(incoming_variable):
    incoming_variable = True

someFunction(bar)

print bar
```

It returns False, when it should return True.

How can I get the variable to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Assignment rebinds the local name to a brand new value, leaving the old value unchanged in the calling scope.

One possible workaround is that mutation doesn't rebind. Pass in a list instead of a boolean, and modify its elements.

```
bar = [False]

def someFunction(incoming_variable):
    incoming_variable[0] = True

someFunction(bar)

print bar[0]
```

You can also mutate class attributes this way.

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None

bar = Thing()
bar.value = False

def someFunction(incoming_variable):
    incoming_variable.value = True

someFunction(bar)

print bar.value
```

And, there's always `global`.

```
bar = False
def someFunction():
    global bar
    bar = True
someFunction()
print bar
```

As well as self-modifying classes.

```
class Widget:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = False
    def someFunction(self):
        self.bar = True

w = Widget()
w.someFunction()
print w.bar
```

But with these last two, you lose the ability to pass different parameters to `someFunction`, so they may not be appropriate. Depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

In your example:

```
bar is global variable existing oustide the scope of function someFunction

Whereas incoming_variable is local variable residing only in the scope of function someFunction
```

calling `someFunction(bar)`:

- assings the value of bar (`False`) to local variable `incoming_variable`
- Evaluates the function

if you want the variable bar to change simply:

```
def someFunction(incoming_variable):
    bar= incoming_variable
```